# Creating a Delete Button in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am Programming in Visual Basic. I have a form that I have created and am using a Data Source from Microsoft Access. I created a Delete button, so users may edit the information. I have written a little bit of code for the Delete button and it deletes the information just fine. I have it display a message asking "are you sure you want to do this?" but whether I click yes or no, it deletes it either way. Could I get some direction on what I need to change so it performs properly? Hopefully this makes sense. Here's what I have so far...

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    '== Enforce Referential Integrity
    If OrdersDataGridView.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then  '== There were no matching orders
        If DialogResult.Yes = MessageBox.Show("You really want to delete this customer?", _
        "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) Then CustomersBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    Else
        If DialogResult.Yes = MessageBox.Show( _
            "There are orders referring to this customer." _
            & vbCrLf & "You must dispose of them somehow before you can delete this customer." _
            & vbCrLf & "Do you wish to delete every matching order now?", _
            "Enforce Referential Integrity", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) Then
            Do Until OrdersDataGridView.CurrentRow Is Nothing
                OrdersBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
            Loop
            CustomersBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, try separating out the result of the click from the user and the boolean test in the If statement and see if that works. Like this:

```
If OrdersDataGridView.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
    Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("You really want to delete this customer?", _
    "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

    If result = DialogResult.No Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        CustomersBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    Else     ' unnecessary, but I like to include it
      'do nothing
    End If

Else
    Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show( _
       "There are orders referring to this customer." _
       & vbCrLf & "You must dispose of them somehow before you can delete this customer." _
       & vbCrLf & "Do you wish to delete every matching order now?", _
       "Enforce Referential Integrity", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

    If result = DialogResult.No Then
       Exit Sub
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
       Do Until OrdersDataGridView.CurrentRow Is Nothing
           OrdersBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
       Loop
       CustomersBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    Else     ' unnecessary, but I like to include it
      ' do nothing
    End If
End If
```

Comment: It still deletes the order if i say no from the dialog box. This is how my code looks now. Hopefully i didn't miss something from what you were saying..

Comment: Sorry, this is probably a dumb question. But i can't seem to figure out how to put a block of code in here :(

Comment: @Luke I've edited my answer to try and store the result into a variable. Try it this way and let me know if it's still deleting when 'no' is pressed. Also to add code in comments you just need to add a tick mark before and after the part you want to look like a block of code `like this` Note that this is the accent mark (above the tab key) not an apostrophe.

Comment: <!-- language: vb.net -->

Comment: Okay i tried that and if you say "no" at the dialog box it deletes a customer and if you say "yes" at the dialog box it deletes two customers.

Comment: If it's still deleting a customer after 'no' is pressed then it is happening somewhere else in your code. Either before or after this block is executed. Post more code or try setting a break point at the beginning of this routine and step through and see where the hidden delete is coming from.

Comment: Okay, i was just thinking. By default is the delete button in the binding navigator set to delete already? if so how do you turn that off?

Comment: Yep that was it... The properties of the binding navigator had the delete button already deleting, so i told it to do nothing. Now it works like a champ.. Thanks so much for your help!